# SQL server 2016 always encrypted certificate stopped working, timeout error

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted

Yesterday the always encrypted certificate stopped working. Which drove my application to a halt. The only response I got from the application was **timeout error**.

I have a `database` with a user table, where `pwd` is encrypted. The web server has the always encrypted certificate installed in the application pool user's personal certificate store. This was going all tickety-boo until the application suddenly was unable to check for login details.

I solved the problem by open MMC as the application pool user and click *refresh* on the Current `User\Personal\Cerificates` store.

Anyone else who has encountered this problem? If so, how did you solve it? As in, how did you prevent it from happening again?

Comment: It happened again yesterday, and I used the powershell command "Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My" to fix the problem.

Comment: I have created this thread in SQL Server forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3874aa2f-0bc4-434d-a74e-6e7d2e7799a6/sql-server-2016-always-encrypted-certificate-stopped-working?forum=sqlsecurity#8f3f1626-0024-47e0-9c6c-5a1ed93a4df0

Answer (score 3):

In IIS (internet information service), Application pool, advanced settings, Process Model, set Load user profile = true. Solved :-)

Comment: Very well, now you can accept your own answer by checking the checkmark next to the answer.